# Correct way to pass parameters containing string into Django Raw sql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-models

I have bunch of complicated sql queries that I need to execute on Django and Raw SQL seems to be the only option. My parameters are strings and can be empty. The reason for being empty is that I have conditional statements above, and depending on that the correct sql needs to be executed. But when the ra sql is run, django actually puts quotes (which I use to denote strings) in the sql and so it throws an error.

I have simplified the query to show the problem I am facing. The following query when executed throws an error.

```
select_cond = ''
where_cond = 'id = 109'

qraw = Book.objects.raw(
        "\
        SELECT  id %s\
        FROM book\
        WHERE %s\
        ",
        [select_cond, where_cond]
)
```

The error is due to it being translated as follows. The quotes actually get in the sql and so it won't execute. Any idea on how I can fix this?

```
 SELECT  id ''
 FROM book
 WHERE 'id = 109'
 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 4):

Django provides a ['params' argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw) for raw that avoids the potential for SQL injection attacks. As @alecxe's example shows, triple quotes in python are a great way to define a multi-line variable and avoid any backslash line escapes.  Here's a proposed safe solution the "Django way":

```
select_cond = condition
where_cond = condition

qraw = Book.objects.raw("""
    SELECT
        id, %(select_cond)s
    FROM
        book
    WHERE
        %(where_cond)s
    """, params={'select_cond': select_cond, 'where_cond': where_cond})
```

Just replace *condition* placeholders with appropriate values.

Answer (score 3):

This is the default behavior of the underlying database driver used by Django.

Note: I'm not sure the motivation behind trying to construct the query this way.

*Only if you trust the source of the where conditions* you are using in the queries, put them into the query via string formatting:

```
qraw = Book.objects.raw("""
    SELECT 
        id, {select}
    FROM 
        book
    WHERE 
        {where}
    """.format(select=select_cond, where=where_cond)
)
```

Again, this is not safe to do since you are actually making it vulnerable to SQL injections.

---

To make it safer you can pre-parse the where conditions you'll be using in the query and call `MySQLdb.escape_string()` manually on the field values, example:

```
key, value = where_cond.split(' = ')
value = MySQLdb.escape_string(value)
where_cond = ' = '.join(key, value)
```

Comment: I guess noting about it being not safe 3 times is not enough to avoid downvotes.